# nodejs/npm/webpack: adding dependency as "file:/some/path" doesn't work

Tags: node.js, webpack, package.json

In **/project-a**, I have a tiny, default exported class that I have built, transpiled and successfully output into a /dist folder. The "main" entry for that project's package.json is therefore "./dist/index.js".

I wanted to try it out before publishing to npm (I am new at this).

In **/project-b**, I update the dependencies in the package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
...
"project-a": "file:C:\\foo\\bar\\project-a"
}
```

And I do:

```
import MyClass from 'project-a';
```

On build with webpack, I get an error along the lines of:

**Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'project-a' in 'C:\webpack\configfile\entry\point'**

So basically, the path to the dependency inside my package.json is being completely ignored! Why? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I figured it out. The tutorial I had been following only showed the end result of the package.json file... so I thought we just had to edit package.json directly with the needed path dependency. But it turns out you're supposed to let the package manager do the edits for you:

So the fix was:

- **delete my manual edits to package.json**
- run `npm install file:../path/to/project-a`

That seemed to make the package system aware of where everything was, and webpack in turn was able to find what it needed to build successfully